# System rake test task doesn't run my tests

Tags: testing, rake, minitest

I'm sure I'm doing something naive or stupid, I'm just not sure what it is.

I'm writing a simple library for parsing data URIs. Being so simple, I figured I'd go ahead and just give ruby-1.9's minitest a whirl. The tests run great when I run them by hand, but when I try to run them with 'rake test', hoping to invoke the system rake test task, I get no joy. Specifically, with trace and verbose:

```
Donalds-Decisiv-MacBook-Pro:data_uri dball$ rake test -t -v
(in /Users/dball/src/data_uri)
** Invoke test (first_time, not_needed)
```

I've got tests in the test folder, they all start with test_ and end in .rb. Any ideas?

The repository of the project is http://github.com/dball/data_uri

Answer (score 3):

Tests are not invoked because you didn't give rake any information about them.

Put this task in `Rakefile`:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
Rake::TestTask.new do |i|
  i.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']
  i.verbose = true
end
```

Or [grab a patch](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24701177/data_uri.patch) for your project.